# Count how many occurrences of a word are there in CSV file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file with data like this

```
PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
111,1,"Ken, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,A
112,2,"Will, Mrs. James",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,B
and so on
```

I want to count how many of these names in the csv file include Mr and Mrs and other

and using column 'sex' I want to print the number of male and female passengers.

I have tried this but it just prints every line with 0 for Mrs and 1 for Mr instead of giving me the count for Names with Mr.

**I dont know how to loop through the csv data, can someone add the code part for that. Thanks.**

```
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>

<script>
            let mycsv = ' some file name';

d3.csv(mycsv, function(data) {
let count = 0;
var theWord  = "Mr";

    if (data.Name.includes(theWord))
    {
        count++;
    }
        
console.log(count);
});

</script>
```

Comment: `data` is an array of "rows". Act accordingly... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: "Mr" is a sub-string of "Mrs". If you search for "Mr" you will also find "Mrs". Either use word boundaries (`\b`) or search for "Mrs" instead.

Comment: @ceving yes I found that out, helps if I add the dot after but I still haven't been able to loop through  and get the count.

Comment: @mplungjan okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need `then` from version 5+

   ```
   let mycsv = 'example.csv';
   d3.csv(mycsv)
   .then(function(data) {
     /* process data */
   })
   ```
2. You need to loop.

That can be done with a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

https://plungjan.name/SO/d3csv/

```js
const process = data =>  {
  const counts = data.reduce((acc, { Name, Sex, Age }) => {
    acc.mr     += Name.toLowerCase().includes("mr.");
    acc.mrs    += Name.toLowerCase().includes("mrs.");
    acc.male   += Sex.toLowerCase() === "male";
    acc.female += Sex.toLowerCase() === "female";
    acc.age    += +Age
    return acc;
  }, { mr: 0, mrs: 0, male: 0, female: 0, age: 0 });
  
  console.log("Total age",counts.age)
  
  Object.entries(counts).forEach(([key,val]) => document.getElementById(key).textContent = val)
}

// uncomment when you want to read a file

// let mycsv = 'example.csv';
// d3.csv(mycsv)
//.then(function(data) {
  process(data)
//})
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>
<script>
  const data = d3.csvParse(`PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
111,1,"Ken, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,A
112,2,"Will, Mrs. James",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,B`);
</script>

Mr: <span id="mr"></span><br/>
Mrs: <span id="mrs"></span><br/>
Male: <span id="male"></span><br/>
Female: <span id="female"></span><br/>
Sum of Ages <span id="age"></span><br/>
```

If you JUST want to count ppl with age above 30:

```js
const process = data =>  {
  const ages = data.map(({Age}) => +Age) // make sure it is a number
  .filter(num => num > 30).length

  console.log("Total of ppl with age above 30:",ages)
}

// uncomment when you want to read a file

// let mycsv = 'example.csv';
// d3.csv(mycsv)
//.then(function(data) {
  process(data)
//})
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>
<script>
  const data = d3.csvParse(`PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
111,1,"Ken, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,A
112,2,"Will, Mrs. James",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,B`);
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work when I try to put a csv file link in place of ----   const data = d3.csvParse(`PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
111,1,"Ken, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,A
112,2,"Will, Mrs. James",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,B`);                                                                           What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It gives me a blank screen, I've updated my code in the question, can you take a look? Could it be because the  csv file might have spaces? Thanks

Comment: Oh I meant to say that the console is blank not the screen.

Comment: Please see updated script

Comment: I added age to my script

Comment: Thanks so much for this help.