# How can I print only the final count onto the console?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a csv file with name and ages of people.
I want to get the count of people under 30.

I have tried the below code.

```
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>
<script>
let thiscsv = 'my csv link here';
let count=0;
d3.csv(thiscsv, function(data) {
 
 if(data.age>30)
 {
   count++
 }

console.log(count);
});
</script>
```

**It checks each line and prints in it the console each time adding 1 count wherever it is true until the end of the csv file.
I want to print only the final count directly onto the console. How can  I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [read the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70751789/5768908) you received for your previous question carefully (and I suggest you upvote it, as I did): the first thing the answerer says is that you need `then()`. This is D3 v7, it doesn't use a callback like D3 v4 or less. The way you're doing now the so called *row function* will run for each parsed row, as expected.

This is what you should do, again, pay attention to the `then()`:

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>
<script>
  let thisCsv = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`name,age
  foo,12
  bar,34
  baz,63
  foobar,17,
  barbar,43,
  barbaz,39`]));
  
  let count = 0;
  
  d3.csv(thisCsv, d3.autoType).then(data => {

    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.age > 30) count++
    });

    console.log(count);
  });
</script>
```

Also, notice the `d3.autoType`: without that, your CSV numbers will be **strings**, not numbers.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, just to be sure, you have shown me count of ages greater than 30 or less than 30 here?

Comment: `if (d.age > 30)`: greater than 30, **not including** 30.

Answer (score 1):

If you JUST want to count ppl with ages above 30:

```js
const process = data =>  {
  const ages = data.map(({Age}) => +Age) // make sure it is a number
  .filter(num => num > 30)
  .length

  console.log("Total ppl with age above 30:",ages)
}

// uncomment when you want to read a file

// let mycsv = 'example.csv';
// d3.csv(mycsv)
//.then(function(data) {
  process(data)
//})
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js'></script>
<script>
  const data = d3.csvParse(`PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
111,1,"Ken, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,A
112,2,"Will, Mrs. James",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,B`);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what data.map does and why we use :  const process = data => and process(data) at the end. Thank you for this answer. I am trying to understand it.

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#live) will create an one to one array from a iterable collection

Comment: `const process = parameter => { ... }` is similar to `function process(parameter) { ... }`

Comment: You can even shorten the call from the `then` : `let mycsv = 'example.csv';
d3.csv(mycsv).then(process);`

Comment: Thank you, if I wanted to print this to the screen instead of the console,  how could I do that? Apologies if I'm bothering you too much.

Comment: Look at the other answer I showed you how